# Identifying result from a Cayley graph in gap

Tags: finite-groups, gap, cayley-graphs

I constructed a group s which is the semidirect product 
$\mathbb{Z}_3 \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)$ using GAP commands as below.

```
gap> m:=[[0,-1],[1,-1]]*One(GF(5));
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2 ] ]

gap> s:=SemidirectProduct(Group(m),GF(5)^2);
Group([ [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
  [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ] ])
```

Then I have obtained an irredundant generating set for s as below and drew the Cayley graph.(There is a .gap program which enables the computation of irredundant generating set as I need).

```
gap> S:=IrredUndirGenSetsUpToAut(s);
[ [ [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, Z(5)^0 ] ] ], 
  [ [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, Z(5)^0 ] ] ] ]

gap> S1:=S[1];
[ [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
  [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, Z(5)^0 ] ] ]

gap> CayleyGraph(s,S1);
rec( adjacencies := [ [ 17, 26, 51, 52 ] ], group := <permutation group of size 75 with 2 generators>, 
  isGraph := true, isSimple := true, 
  names := [ [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, Z(5)^0 ] ], 
      [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ], ...
```

In the Cayley graph is this list showing the vertices in the order they are connected?

Does the list above mean that the vertices are connected as $(\bar{1},\bar{0},\bar{0}) to (\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{0}) to (\bar{0},\bar{0},\bar{1}) to (\bar{0},\bar{4},\bar{0})$ and so on?

And in the triplet  [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], is the first element from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and the 2nd and 3rd elements from $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)$?

Please help me with this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The code is quite unreadable - you need to indent it by four spaces to make it look like after my edits.

Comment: Don't have time to look now, but have you seen https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP002.htm and https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP002.htm#SECT007 ?

Comment: Yes. But I can not figure out answers to my questions from that. I want to clarify about the things I've mentioned. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to call `CayleyGraph` on some smaller examples where you know how the Cayley graph should look like?

Comment: P.S. Look at functions to inspect graphs at https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP003.htm, in particular `DirectedEdges` - that should help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: In the cayley graph for semidirect product I thought a vertex is represented by an element from the group (which is the semidirect product), so that I thought it should be of the form $(\bar{1},\bar{0},\bar{0})$. i.e. the first vertex is represented by a triplet like $(\bar{1},\bar{0},\bar{0})$ and so on. But when I check the Vertex names it gives me 3 such triplets as the first vertex. e.g. $(\bar{1},\bar{0},\bar{0}),(\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{0}),(\bar{0},\bar{0},\bar{1})$. Does that mean I have to do some computation to these 3 coordinates to get it to the form I want.

Comment: I would like to get an understanding about the vertices in the cayley graph of the semidirect product.

Comment: A list of three lists of lists three is a matrix - because `SemidirectProduct(Group(m),GF(5)^2)` is constructed as a matrix group. I think you need to look at `Embedding` and `Projection` as shown in https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49.html#X7D905A5778D7ACDE to be able to interpret it in terms of `Group(m)` and `GF(5)^2`. There are two separate questions here - how to interpret the output of `SemidirectProduct` and then how to interpret the output of `CayleyGraph`.